# ListPopupWindow menu popup animation direction from left to right

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a ListPopupMenu with code as below

```
public void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(getActivity());
    listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new CollectionItemMenuAdapter(getActivity(), popupMenuList));
    listPopupWindow.setWidth((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_width));
    listPopupWindow.setHeight(WRAP_CONTENT);
    listPopupWindow.setVerticalOffset((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_vertical_offset));
    listPopupWindow.setHorizontalOffset((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menu_horizontal_offset));

    listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(view);
    listPopupWindow.show();
}
```

The result is as below, when click on the setting (in the gif, the first one), the popup menu appear.

[image]

However the menu animation appears from Right to Left. I would prefer it to show from Left to Right (like appearing from the setting button). Could I achieve that without creating a custom animation for it?

p/s: I tried custom animation using `listPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(...)`, also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my problem is mainly due to sending the wrong view over to `listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(view);`. I need to send the "setting-image" view instead of the "parent-list-view".

By sending the right view, I now have the animation starting from the right source i.e. the point of the setting image. The fixed animation is shown below
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I made in this way.

First, make animation set in res/anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
   <scale android:fromXScale="0" android:fromYScale="1"
      android:toXScale="1" android:toYScale="1"
      android:duration="700"
      />
</set>
```

second, add style in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="Animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/animation</item>
</style>
```

and use setAnimationStyle.

```
popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
```

This is PopupWindow. but i think they are both the same way.

good luck !!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, as I mentioned in my question, `listPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);` is not working for me :(, especially now I have a fixed width of the menu.